# update stock with cumulative sum of a column sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database table with columns ID, Date, and Stock. I want to add a column called Order to show as 1 at start and zero until the next cumulative sum reaches one.

Here is my sample data - the desired result is in the sample Order column:

```
ID  Date         Stock  Order
1   01-Jan-2017  0.17   1
1   01-Feb-2017  0.17   0
1   01-Mar-2017  0.17   0
1   01-Apr-2017  0.17   0
1   01-May-2017  0.17   0
1   01-Jun-2017  0.17   0
1   01-Jul-2017  0.17   1
1   01-Aug-2017  0.17   0
1   01-Sep-2017  0.17   0
1   01-Oct-2017  0.17   0
1   01-Nov-2017  0.17   0
1   01-Dec-2017  0.17   0
1   01-Jan-2018  0.17   1
1   01-Feb-2018  0.17   0
1   01-Mar-2018  0.17   0
1   01-Apr-2018  0.17   0
1   01-May-2018  0.17   0
1   01-Jun-2018  0.17   0
1   01-Jul-2018  0.17   1
1   01-Aug-2018  0.17   0
1   01-Sep-2018  0.17   0
1   01-Oct-2018  0.17   0
1   01-Nov-2018  0.17   0
```

Comment: ID Date Stock Order
1 01-Jan-2017  0.17  1
1 01-Feb-2017  0.17  0
1 01-Mar-2017  0.17  0
1 01-Apr-2017  0.17  0
1 01-May-2017  0.17  0
1 01-Jun-2017  0.17  0
1 01-Jul-2017  0.17  1
1 01-Aug-2017  0.17  0
1 01-Sep-2017  0.17  0
1 01-Oct-2017  0.17  0
1 01-Nov-2017  0.17  0
1 01-Dec-2017  0.17  0
1 01-Jan-2018  0.17  1
1 01-Feb-2018  0.17  0
1 01-Mar-2018  0.17  0
1 01-Apr-2018  0.17  0
1 01-May-2018  0.17  0
1 01-Jun-2018  0.17  0
1 01-Jul-2018  0.17  1
1 01-Aug-2018  0.17  0
1 01-Sep-2018  0.17  0
1 01-Oct-2018  0.17  0
1 01-Nov-2018  0.17  0

Comment: Can you please clear your requirement, not able to get your question

Comment: The stock is the value of stock i have to but to have in my inventory. As in jan it is .17 i will buy and give the product in my inventory. now when the cumulative sum reaches 1+ i have to order one more.

Comment: The stock is the value of stock i have to but to have in my inventory. As in jan it is .17 i will buy and give the product in my inventory. now when the cumulative sum reaches 1+ i have to order one more. Stock in example is simple.17 but in actual it can be any decimal digit for each month. EX .17 for JAn, .56 for FEB etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace @t with your table name:

```
select id, date, stock, cumu_val, case when cumu_val = 0 then 1 when intval <> lastintval then 1 else 0 end as [order]
from
(
    SELECT id, date, stock, (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(stock), 0) FROM @t WHERE date < t.date) as cumu_val, 
        FLOOR((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(stock), 0) FROM @t WHERE date < t.date)) intval, 
        FLOOR((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(stock), 0) FROM @t WHERE date < (select top 1 date from @t where date < t.date order by date desc))) lastintval
    FROM @t t
)sq
```

Here's some sample output

```
id   date          stock    cumu_val    order
1    2017-01-01    0.17     0.00        1
1    2017-02-01    0.37     0.17        0
1    2017-03-01    0.57     0.54        0
1    2017-04-01    0.67     1.11        1
1    2017-05-01    0.37     1.78        0
1    2017-06-01    0.27     2.15        1
1    2017-07-01    0.17     2.42        0
1    2017-08-01    0.70     2.59        0
1    2017-09-01    0.17     3.29        1
1    2017-10-01    0.07     3.46        0
1    2017-11-01    0.07     3.53        0
1    2017-12-01    0.17     3.60        0
1    2018-01-01    0.27     3.77        0
1    2018-02-01    0.37     4.04        1
```

Comment: above script runs fine, but if the stock are random as .17 for Jan and .39 for Feb and .66 for March. above scripts fails.

Comment: @Ansh updated allowing for variability in the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select [id],[date],[stock],IIF([cumstock] is null , 0 , [cumstock]) [cumstock] ,
IIF(cumstock_lag is null and cumstock is null,1,IIF(cumstock_lag is null, 0 , IIF(floor(cumstock_lag)<>floor(cumstock) , 1 , 0 ) ) ) [reorder]  
from (
   select [id],[date],[stock],lag_date,
        (select sum(t4.[stock]) from dbo.teststock t4 where t4.[date] < t3.[lag_date]) as [cumstock_lag],
        (select sum(t5.[stock]) from dbo.teststock t5 where t5.[date] <= t3.[lag_date]) as [cumstock] 
        from (
            select [id],[date],[stock],(select max(t2.[date]) from dbo.teststock t2 where t2.[date] < t.[date]) as [lag_date]  from dbo.teststock t 
    ) t3
) t6
```

Assuming dates are unique,
produces the following using two nested less than comparisons to build the lag structure that could be done with window functions for 2012+. cumulative sum is built using subqueries in select clause.

```
1   2017-01-01  0.17    0   1
1   2017-02-01  0.17    0.17    0
1   2017-03-01  0.17    0.34    0
1   2017-04-01  0.17    0.51    0
1   2017-05-01  0.17    0.68    0
1   2017-06-01  0.17    0.85    0
1   2017-07-01  0.17    1.02    1
1   2017-08-01  0.17    1.19    0
1   2017-09-01  0.17    1.36    0
1   2017-10-01  0.17    1.53    0
1   2017-11-01  0.17    1.7 0
1   2017-12-01  0.17    1.87    0
1   2018-01-01  0.17    2.04    1
1   2018-02-01  0.17    2.21    0
1   2018-03-01  0.17    2.38    0
1   2018-04-01  0.17    2.55    0
1   2018-05-01  0.17    2.72    0
1   2018-06-01  0.17    2.89    0
1   2018-07-01  0.17    3.06    1
1   2018-08-01  0.17    3.23    0
1   2018-09-01  0.17    3.4 0
1   2018-10-01  0.17    3.57    0
1   2018-11-01  0.17    3.74    0
```

Comment: the rank function doesnt work either, then. hmmm. does the solution have to be a single query, or are temp tables and the like ok?

Comment: it has to be a simple query, i also have the solution with temp table and variable.

Comment: whole bunch of subqueries it is then.

Comment: I dont have the answer, i am also search for it.